# Truncate does not physically release the diskspace

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `spring-data` with `CrudRepository` for any database access. Once a day I also have to truncate a cached table with approx 100GB of data and rebuild it.

Problem: The table is truncated successfully (I verified table is empty), BUT the file are not physically deleted from the harddrive of the database!

```
interface MyTableRepository extends CrudRepository<MyTableEntity, Long> {
    @Query(value = "TRUNCATE TABLE my_table", nativeQuery = true)
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    void truncateTable();
}
```

As a result, the harddrive space gets less from day to day.
What I noticed: if I close my java application, then instantly the before `truncated` parts of the `postgres` table are removed!

What could be the cause of this?

When I use pgAdmin to truncate the same table, the diskspace is released as expected.

Comment: Sounds as if you are not committing the `truncate` properly

Comment: The commit should be automatically handled by `@Transactional`

Comment: Maybe it *should*, but from your description I'd say it doesn't. What does `pg_stat_activity` show you for your application's connection _before_ you disconnect your Java app? Maybe spring doesn't know it needs to commit a `truncate` statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hm, that shows about 40 idle connections. Whereas half of them are `set extra_float_digits = 3`, and the other half are `COPY FROM STDIN` which is the command I fill the table with. I can also spot one pid with sql `COMMIT`, and three with empty query.

Comment: Are there other active transactions that access the same table? If they have started before the truncate, then until they are finished, the table will not be released.

Comment: The only active connection currently comes from the pgadmin tool that I executed the `pg_stat_activity` query with. The rest is idle.

Comment: Are they "idle" or "idle in transaction"?

Comment: they are `idle` only, no transaction in progress

Comment: The fact that it works fine from your SQL client but not when you run the statement through your obfuscation layer,  means that something in that layer is wrong. Try running the statement with plain JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons

1. PostgresSQL would delete this index file after vacuum. So wait or vacuum by yourself
2. SQL is not committed until you quit this java program

Comment: For 2) I can say: using pgAdmin I can see a truncated empty table! So I assume the sql is actually commited, as otherwise I would not see an empty db? Point 1): shouldn't I see a vacuum pid in the list if anything is still ongoing? I don't see any vacuum process, nor do I think that the vacuum does not finish after several days (but the harddrive contains database files also from last week, even though these data was truncated long ago)...

Comment: ahh, yes. I am wrong. Truncate will delelte the file immediately